# Mysql привести 2 столбца к единому идентификатору

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица сообщений вида:

```
|id|sender_id|recipient_id|     date_sent     |
_______________________________________________
|1 |    100  |     101    |2017-03-02 08:03:45|
-----------------------------------------------
|2 |    100  |     101    |2017-03-02 08:10:45|
-----------------------------------------------
|3 |    101  |     100    |2017-03-02 09:55:01|
```

И так далее. Для расшифровки:

1. ID сообщения
2. ID отправителя сообщения
3. ID получателя сообщения
4. Дата отправки сообщения
   Есть еще поля типа самого сообщения, но в вопросе оно никчему.

Нужно:

Вывести диалоги для конкретного юзера с каждым другим юзером, с которым он общался. (сообщения вконтакте для примера).
Т.е. мне нужно оставить по **последнему** сообщению с каждым юзером.
Причем, если (как я пытался) повесить group by на sender_id, то в случае исходящего сообщения все ок, а если сообщения входящие (без ответа), они минуют group by. Все это пробовал и через MAX по [даному](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/18.html) совету. В теории вроде понятно, но на практике все уходит в пропасть. У меня 2 идентификатора и как их превратить в единый (чтобы запрос понимал, что 100 и 101, и 101 и 100 это один диалог.
Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такое вот:

```
SELECT *
FROM dialogs 
WHERE (LEAST(sender_id, recipient_id), GREATEST(sender_id, recipient_id), date_sent) IN
    (
    SELECT LEAST(sender_id, recipient_id), GREATEST(sender_id, recipient_id), MAX(date_sent)
    FROM dialogs 
    WHERE @user IN (sender_id, recipient_id)
    GROUP BY LEAST(sender_id, recipient_id), GREATEST(sender_id, recipient_id)
    )
```

Comment: Круто! Работает, правда данных недостаточно в таблице, чтобы проверить все кардинально, буду тестировать. Я думал разбираюсь в sql запросах, но не понял, что Вы тут сделали. Подскажите литературу, чтобы с легкостью такие запросы составлять??

Comment: Да простейший же запрос... тут не нужно никакой литературы, голая логика. А чтобы с лёгкостью - это разбор решений разнообразных реальных задач, предложенных на этом и других сайтах, плюс практика (постараться на те же задачи до прочтения ответов придумать собственное решение или хотя бы алгоритм).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой подход (мне сейчас, к сожалению, не на чем проверить):

```
SELECT all_dialogs.sender_id, all_dialogs.recipient_id, MAX(all_dialogs.date_sent)
FROM 
(
  SELECT sender_id, recipient_id, date_sent
  FROM dialogs 
  WHERE sender_id = @user_id 
  GROUP BY  sender_id, recipient_id

  UNION ALL 
  SELECT recipient_id, sender_id, date_sent
  FROM dialogs 
  WHERE recipient_id  = @user_id 
  GROUP BY sender_id, recipient_id 
) all_dialogs
GROUP BY all_dialogs.sender_id, all_dialogs.recipient_id
```

Comment: Сообщения вывел верно (по кол-вам диалогов), но не по последней дате

Answer (score 0):

> чтобы запрос понимал, что 100 и 101, и 101 и 100 это один диалог

Ваша текущая структура данных крайне неудобна для этих целей.
Как бонус - она создаёт непреодолимые препятствия при попытке организовать групповой чат.

Предлагаю другую структуру:

```
Conversation (id, created, created_by)
Participants (conversation_id, user_id)
Messages (id, conversation_id, user_id(или participant_id), date_sent, content)
```

Т.е. появляются сущности самих диалогов, участников диалогов, и собственно сообщений.

Тогда ваша задача будет решаться например так:

```
SELECT m.id FROM Conversation c
JOIN Participants p ON c.id = p.conversation_id
JOIN Messages m ON m.conv_id = c.id
WHERE p.user_id = :user_id
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING m.date_sent = MAX(m.date_sent)
ORDER BY m.date_sent DESC
```

На реальной структуре данных, можно будет размышлять об оптимизации.

Comment: Увы, приложение уже готовое и большое, написанное не мной. Менять структуру - значит менять кучу php классов и методов.